# Growing log data

Tags: c#, database, optimization, logging, database-performance

In an application of ours (booking/reservation type) we are handling the log data through a single `DBAudit` table.

The problem is that, because of the growth of the data in this table, the reports generated on the basis of it have slowed down 'massively'. What are the options (**time proof**)?

Can these be valid choices :

1. Handle log through multiple tables
2. Auto delete old data periodically
3. Migrate old data to some other archive database

How do other applications with huge activity logs maintain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try pre-calculating important metrics in your data every so often and then build your reports off those metrics.

This will allow you to archive out your old log data into a data-warehouse without affecting your reports.

Comment: Impressive concept ! Thanks pro :)

Comment: pre-calculated metrics shall be maintained in some other table i guess ?

Comment: Yes in separate tables without foreign keys to the original production data. A windows service that runs in the background can calculate every night or week, whatever is best for your scenario. I did this for a client and it worked very well. The trade-off being that reports aren't realtime (which is acceptable most of the time).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all of these are good options and you should probably try to implement all of these:

1. Handle log through multiple tables – maybe consider keeping only the latest data in main tables and then moving them to some history tables later. It depends on how much data is really needed for running your reports.
2. Auto delete old data periodically – I’d consider calculating the metrics first before deleting the data. Try creating as many different metrics as possible that will consume less space and then when data is processed just keep the results and delete the actual data.
3. Migrate old data to some other archive database – I would do this only in case you really can’t afford to delete any data.

Other than this you can always try with adding indexes to the reporting tables for the most used columns and/or try to optimize queries as much as possible. If there are already indexes in those tables make sure you are regularly re-building these.